# HOSTS file entries leading to permissions issues - Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, networking, permissions, windows-server-2012, hosts-file

We have a HOSTS file that maps a document server to an IP address of the local machine, it looks similar to this:

```
DocumentServer   10.xx.xx.11
```

The local IP address being 10.xx.xx.11

We are hitting permission issues whenever we visit:

```
\\DocumentServer\
```

We have no way of getting access to this folder, local admin credentials do not work.

However, if we attempt to navigate to the machine name share or either of the following we are not hitting any permission issues

```
\\10.xx.xx.11\
\\localhost\
```

Has anyone run into this kind of issue before? I can't seem to find any information on it

Comment: I assume a "ping DocumentServer" returns the correct 10.xx.xx.11 address?  i.e., it's reading the hosts file properly?

Comment: Yes, it's pinging properly, no packets lost. It is reading the HOSTS file correctly, but the permission issue only occurs whenever you try to navigate to the UNC path the HOSTS reference is mapped to

Comment: I would assume no packets would be lost, since you can get to it by IP address. I was more interested in whether DocumentServer resolved to 10.xx.xx.11. When you say "the permission issue", I assume that you're getting an "access denied" error, or is there a different message? Is there anything in the Event Logs?

Comment: DocumentServer resolved to 10.xx.xx.11. All I was getting was an  "access denied" error, along with a prompt for a username and password, even though no users (even local administrators) were being granted access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the problem stems from certain Microsoft 'security features'.

**Strict Name Checking** and **Authentication Loopback Check** to be specific.

These checks block any user from navigating locally to a self-referencing HOSTS entry. This is my own understanding, feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

The steps I followed are outlined and explained in detail in [Rob Wilcox's Symantec post](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/why-you-might-disable-strict-name-checking-and-authentication-loopback-enterprise-vault-server)

1. Running Regedit as an admin, navigate to:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
   ```
2. Add a new **DWORD** here called **DisableStrictNameChecking**, set the value to **1**
3. Next, navigate to:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
   ```
4. Add a new **DWORD** here called **DisableLoopbackCheck**, set the value to **1**
5. Restart after setting both.

Comment: Glad to hear you found your answer.